# The language expression property '0' can't be evaluated, property name must be a string.' ARM Templates

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-resource-manager, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am trying to create cosmos DB and running a copy function to create container in the ARM template. But I am getting the Expression Error.

> The language expression property '0' can't be evaluated.', for both indexes

Here is the variable Part:

```
 "autoscaleOptions" : {
        "copy": [
        {
          "name": "autoscaleSettings",
          "count": "[length(parameters('containers'))]",
          "input": {
          "throughput": "[parameters('containers')[copyIndex('autoscaleSettings')].throughput]",
            "autoscaleSettings": {
              "maxThroughput": "[if(parameters('containers')[copyIndex('autoscaleSettings')].autoscale, null(), parameters('containers')[copyIndex('autoscaleSettings')].maxThroughput)]"
            }
          }
        }
        ]
      }
```

How I am calling the variable:

```
{
        "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases/collections",
        "apiVersion": "2021-04-15",
        "name": "[format('{0}/{1}/{2}', variables('accountName_var'), parameters('databaseName'), parameters('containers')[copyIndex()].name)]",
        "copy": {
          "count": "[length(parameters('containers'))]",
          "name": "ContainerCopy"
        },
        "properties": {
          "resource": {
            "id": "[parameters('containers')[copyIndex('ContainerCopy')].name]"
          },
          "options": "[variables('autoscaleOptions')[copyIndex('ContainerCopy')].input]"
          
        },
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases', variables('accountName_var'), parameters('databaseName'))]",
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', variables('accountName_var'))]"
        ]
      }
```

Here I have uploaded the entire template which has all the parameters.
https://gist.github.com/PrakashRajanSakthivel/cc2495e82102d9c9569461eb4a96c75f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to achieve it, its because of the autoscale and manual depends on one another which shouldn't. here is the working one. https://gist.github.com/PrakashRajanSakthivel/17cca682ec0aba049561975142e828f7